# How can I convert this byte or string to a dataframe?

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have a data in this format(bytes):

```
b'{"datatable":{"data":[["AAPL","1980-12-12",28.75,28.87,28.75,28.75,2093900.0,0.0,1.0,0.42270591588018,0.42447025361603,0.42270591588018,0.42270591588018,117258400.0],
["AAPL","1980-12-15",27.38,27.38,27.25,27.25,785200.0,0.0,1.0,0.40256306006259,0.40256306006259,0.40065169418209,0.40065169418209,43971200.0],
["AAPL","1980-12-16",25.37,25.37,25.25,25.25,472000.0,0.0,1.0,0.37301040298714,0.37301040298714,0.37124606525129,0.37124606525129,26432000.0],
["AAPL","1980-12-17",25.87,26.0,25.87,25.87,385900.0,0.0,1.0,0.38036181021984,0.38227317610034,0.38036181021984,0.38036181021984,21610400.0],
["AAPL","1980-12-18",26.63,26.75,26.63,26.63,327900.0,0.0,1.0,0.39153594921354,0.39330028694939,0.39153594921354,0.39153594921354,18362400.0],
["AAPL","1980-12-19",28.25,28.38,28.25,28.25,217100.0,0.0,1.0,0.41535450864748,0.41726587452798,0.41535450864748,0.41535450864748,12157600.0],
.....,{"name":"adj_high","type":"BigDecimal(50,28)"},{"name":"adj_low","type":"BigDecimal(50,28)"},{"name":"adj_close","type":"BigDecimal(50,28)"},{"name":"adj_volume","type":"double"}]},"meta":{"next_cursor_id":null}}'
```

I can convert this by using `.decode('utf-8')`. However, I want to convert the type into DataFrame or some other format so that I can work with this data.
Any help would be appreciated.

Here are errors when I try `pd.DataFrame()`

```
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Thank you for giving me great direction!
I have used

```
apple = json.loads(apple1)
apple
```

to get

```
{'datatable': {'columns': [{'name': 'ticker', 'type': 'String'},
    {'name': 'date', 'type': 'Date'},
    {'name': 'open', 'type': 'BigDecimal(34,12)'},
    {'name': 'high', 'type': 'BigDecimal(34,12)'},
    {'name': 'low', 'type': 'BigDecimal(34,12)'},
    {'name': 'close', 'type': 'BigDecimal(34,12)'},
    {'name': 'volume', 'type': 'BigDecimal(37,15)'},
    {'name': 'ex-dividend', 'type': 'BigDecimal(42,20)'},
    {'name': 'split_ratio', 'type': 'double'},
    {'name': 'adj_open', 'type': 'BigDecimal(50,28)'},
    {'name': 'adj_high', 'type': 'BigDecimal(50,28)'},
    {'name': 'adj_low', 'type': 'BigDecimal(50,28)'},
    {'name': 'adj_close', 'type': 'BigDecimal(50,28)'},
    {'name': 'adj_volume', 'type': 'double'}],
   'data': [['AAPL',
     '1980-12-12',
     28.75,
     28.87,
     28.75,
     28.75,
     2093900.0,
     0.0,
     1.0,
     0.42270591588018,
     0.42447025361603,
     0.42270591588018,
     0.42270591588018,
     117258400.0],
    ['AAPL',
     '1980-12-15',
     27.38,
     27.38,
     27.25,
     27.25,
     785200.0,
     0.0,
     1.0,
     0.40256306006259,
     0.40256306006259,
     0.40065169418209,
     0.40065169418209,
     43971200.0],
```

and if I run:

```
pd.DataFrame(apple['datatable']['data'])
```

I get:

[apple dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Drl2h.png)

Which is good, but I would like to have column name as: `[date, open, high, low, close, volume, ex-dividend, split_ratio, adj_open, adj_high, adj_low, adj_close, adj_volume]` rather than `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]`.

Also, I would like to delete current column 1('AAPL') and index as numbers so that it looks like a time series with date as the first column.

Can you help me on this?

Comment: Looks like you might need this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Answer (score 0):

You might need to tidy up the data first but doing the following works.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))['datatable']['data'])
```